# MySQL How to `SUM` a value on a many-to-one relationship, in the case that there are multiple values take only 1 the Maximum?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to `SUM` the number of employees_affected after a specific project_date from a specific region, **in the case where there is 2 or more projects per business, the project record with the maximum employees should be taken (ie. employees_affected only counted once per business, the maximum)?**

### Project

- project_id
- employees_affected
- project_date
- Cancelled (bool)
- Awarded (bool)
- enterpriseid

### Business

- id
- region
- name

What I have so far (some subtitle differences in terms of checking date etc):

```
SELECT SUM(employees_affected) AS `employees` 
FROM `project` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `business` AS `b` ON b.id = p.enterpriseid 
WHERE (awarded = 1) 
AND (b.region = 3)
AND (cancelled = 0) 
AND (YEAR(project_date) = '2014') 
AND (MONTH(project_date) = '06') LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by businesses and take the maximum employees of each group:

```
select sum(employees) from 
(select max(employees_affected) AS `employees` 
    FROM `project` AS `p` 
    LEFT JOIN `business` AS `b` 
    ON b.id = p.enterpriseid WHERE (awarded = 1) 
        AND (b.region = 3)
        AND (cancelled = 0) 
        AND (YEAR(project_date) = 2014) 
        AND (MONTH(project_date) = 6) 
   GROUP BY enterpriseid
) x
```